# Does the turtlebot need wifi access to build a map?

Tags: ros, navigation, wireless, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the turtlebot actually need a wifi connection to operate?  I want to build a map of a large area in my office building.  The building has wifi coverage, but it is spotty and sometimes the connection gets dropped.

I would like to drive the turtlebot around with a wireless joystick, and build a map using the gmapping tutorial.  My question is, if the turtlebot's netbook loses the wireless connection along the way, will this cause problems with the processes?

Basically, I want to:

1. bringup the turtlebot
2. start the gmapping app:
   roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch
3. Check from the workstation that the dashboard is ok (and then close it).
4. Start the joystick telop and drive around and build the map.

I am worried that if the wireless connection is dropped while I am driving it around to build the map, that ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_MASTER_URI will no longer resolve on the turtlebot and the map app will fail.

Please let me know if there are any tricks to building a map like this, or if I am going about it incorrectly.  It tried a short mapping experiment using key teleoperation from the workstation, and that failed when the connection was dropped.  So, I am trying to understand the requirements better.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12967/does-the-turtlebot-need-wifi-access-to-build-a-map?/) by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 332 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run all of the processes on the turtlebot itself, you won't have any problems. It may be helpful to use [gnu screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) so your nodes don't die when the turtlebot loses its network connection and the SSH sessions disconnect.

Additionally, if the ROS_MASTER_URI is set to localhost, it does not matter if you actually have a network connection.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2